# PHP Regex, Get last word after different characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find out how to get the last word of a string, However the character im trying to match it too isn't always the same. For example

```
This is a file (USA) -LastWord
This is another file (EUR) ~LastWord
This is another different file (JPN) LastWord
```

How can i match against this? I always want to just return "LastWord"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will suggest using:

```
/\b\w+(?=\W*$)/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD7eM0/1)

This will match last word optionally followed by 0 or more non-word characters like period. (See demo)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to get the last word.

```
\w+$
```

`$` matches the end of a line. `\w+` matches one or more word characters. Add multiline `m` modifier whenever anchors are used.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dG9lM6/2)

```
$re = "/\\w+$/m";
$str = "This is a file (USA) -LastWord\nThis is another file (EUR) ~LastWord\nThis is another different file (JPN) LastWord";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be returning any results.

Comment: explanation that `$` is end of string and `\w` is `a-z` group, `+` is one or more char, you're missing `i` modifier

Comment: you must need to add multiline modifier.